# Error Attempting to upload file: expected str, bytes, or os.Pathlike object, not Streaming Body

Tags: python

I'm writing python code that gets a file from an S3 bucket and sends the file to a destination server via FTP, using ftplib.

I need the option to send using storbinary or storlines. When using storbinary, it works but when using storlines I get an error that it's expecting "str, bytes, or os.Pathlike object, not Streamingbody"

I've looked and couldn't find any example of someone else having this issue. Is it possible to treat the botocore Streamingbody as a file like object to be uploaded?

```
if mode == 'ascii':
    ftp.storlines('STOR ' + file_name, src_file)
else:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR' + file_name, src_file)
```

Expecting the file to be uploaded, but get error "expected str, bytes, or os.Pathlike object, not Streamingbody"

Comment: Show us how `src_file` is created.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `ftplib` and `boto3`, you can try something like this:

```py
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP(...)
obj = client.get_object(Bucket='mybucket', Key='objkey')
ftp.storbinary('STOR file.bin', obj['Body'])
```

I guess you need to index `src_file` as `src_file['Body']`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using the following. I had to read the file and wrap it into a bytes object.

```
import ftplib

if mode == 'ascii':
    file_stream = src_file.read()
    bytes_obj = BytesIO(file_stream)
    ftp.storlines('STOR ' + file_name, bytes_obj)
else:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR' + file_name, src_file)
```